# How do I use a framework in a framework with Carthage?

Tags: ios, xcode, carthage

I have created a Swift framework following [this](http://basememara.com/creating-cross-platform-swift-frameworks-ios-watchos-tvos-via-carthage-cocoapods/) guide. This works in client apps and can also be tested.

So far, so good.

When I add a framework to my framework, e.g. [JASON](https://github.com/delba/JASON), I can't import into my code because it doesn't show up.

```
error: no such module 'JASON'
import JASON
       ^
```

Interestingly, I can import the framework in my unit test target. Which is not where I want or need it.

I've also followed Robot's [advice](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/creating-your-first-ios-framework) in addition to Carthage's [advice](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage#adding-frameworks-to-unit-tests-or-a-framework).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Adding a framework to another framework project as a dependency is fine with Carthage. I've done it on my own projects at home (Objective-C) and at work (Swift).

The trick is when adding the projects to your app. the best method I have found is to use a flat model. ie. Don't try and embed frameworks or somehow nest them. Let Carthage bring your top level frameworks in and any frameworks they depend on, all at the same level. Then drag their *.framework files into you app project and also add them in a separate build step using the `carthage copy-frameworks` command.

Comment: I think the fact that Carthage lets you specify a Cartfile.private that you must be able to best frameworks. Unless that's just for testing frameworks, but the docs don't say so.

Comment: @drekka So your cocoa touch framework should have `carthage copy-frameworks` command? Or maybe app that u embedded your framework with?

Answer (score 1):

I recently jumped into a similar issue and spend some quality time figuring out the solution. I could find the answer in Carthage Github page under section "Nested dependencies"

https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage#nested-dependencies